# Записать логическое выражение в условие фунции

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список, списки

Надо написать с помощью функции написать аналог filter (в рамках обучения - пользоваться специальными функциями нельзя). Но непонятно как в функцию записать логическое выражение. 
Например: есть список c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,-1]
Надо функцию:

```
def foo(c, a = i>5):
    b = []
        for i in c:
            if a:
                b.append(i)
    return(b)
```

Должно возвращать [6,7].
Но как правильно записать условие i>5 правильно, непонятно. Может быть другое (<,>=,<=,==).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [данным решением (c) @alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18591880/5741205):

```
import operator


def get_truth(inp, relate, cut):
    ops = {'>': operator.gt,
           '<': operator.lt,
           '>=': operator.ge,
           '<=': operator.le,
           '==': operator.eq}
    return ops[relate](inp, cut)


c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,-1]
items = [i for i in c if get_truth(i, '>', 5)]
print(items)  # [6, 7]
```

---

функциональное [решение от @gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851111/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/851121#comment1370120_851121):

```
items = list(filter(lambda i: get_truth(i, '>', 5), c))
print(items)  # [6, 7]
```

Comment: Дополнительно можно функциональный пример добавить: `items = list(filter(lambda i: get_truth(i, '>', 5), c))` :)

Comment: @gil9red, так у ТС интерес в написании своей реализации фильтра

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо! добавил в ответ...

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import lt
from functools import partial

c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,-1]   

def foo_filter(sequence, predicat=lambda _: True):
    # если предикат не передан, вся последовательность пройдет фильтр

    b = []
    for i in sequence:
        if predicat(i):
            b.append(i)
    return b

# partial(lt, 5) = lt(5, x) = if 5 < x
print(foo_filter(c, partial(lt, 5)))  # [6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def _filter(function, iterable):
    for i in iterable:
        if function(i):
            yield i

list(_filter(str.isdigit, ['1', '2', 'b', ]))
```